# Loading Bar - Bash Script

Tags: linux, bash, percentage

I've seen code that shows a loading bar for copying and extracting files in a bash script. I've tried modifying it to work without luck. Is there a way to display an accurate and basic loading bar while OpenVPN loads/connects? Maybe even echo if there's a connection error? (Not as important) I need the output of starting OpenVPN to stay hidden.

```
openvpn --daemon --config /tmp/OpenVPN/config.ovpn >/dev/null 2>/dev/null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as your command doesn't offer a way to display its progress, there is no trivial way to implement this, as your bash script cannot know how far in its execution is it.

`openvpn` doesn't seem to offer such an option, so in this case, I don't think this would be possible without patching its source code and recompiling it.

If you want to display connection errors, you can use `||` though:

`openvpn --daemon --config /tmp/OpenVPN/config.ovpn >/dev/null 2>/dev/null || echo "openvpn return with an error"`